# Using WinForm Paint event inside groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, groupbox

I am tryign to port over this C++ MFC application into a C# WinForm. It is a work in progress. Basically, I want to do some drawing into the groupbox area:

[image: Dialog design]

I added a Paint handler to the Form to do my work:

```
private void FullColourPaletteForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Do painting with e.Graphics
}
```

I was surprised to see that it did not show my rendering. But, then I realised that in a Winform it is not called a `groupbox` but a `container`. So, I set the container to be invisible and understandably my rendering (albeit not quite right) was now visble:

[image: Dialog results]

How am I supposed to do my painting within the area of the container?

Why is this then? All I did was add:

```
private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Now my forms painting is visible.

Comment: Use the GroupBox's Paint event instead.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Each control has own paint events. When form is drawn (when visibility is changed) each control `OnPaint` method is called (which at the end of painting calls `Paint` event). What you are trying to do is creating a custom control to draw palette. It doesn't have to be `GroupBox`, you can use `Control` instead. If you want to keep that `GroupBox` border then you can override `Paint` method and call `base.OnPaint` first and then draw on top of that. Not sure if this is the case, but sometimes it's worth to draw everything yourself (you can use `ControlPaint.DrawBorder` to draw border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each window (control, form etc.) has its own painting, and children are normally clipped (excluded) from that painting.

If you want to draw inside the `GroupBox` (or any control), you should handle that in the corresponding control (`GroupBox` in your case) `Paint` event, not the form one.

```
private void groupBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var area = groupBox.DisplayRectangle;
    // Draw inside the area
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, area);
}
```

Comment: I ended up putting a `PictureBox` box inside it and used the `Paint` event of that because it supports `DoubleBuffering` natively.